# Check for equal values in lists and set them to 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist, list-comprehension

I want the elements from list a to be zero in list b

```
a = [80,85,140,145]

b = list(range(200))
```

Is there a way to do it instead of writing it manually:

```
b[80]=0

b[140]=0
```

because I am running simulations and the values in list a and also the list length of a are always changing from one simulation to another and I would like to find a way to automatically set the values of list a to 0 in list b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a list comprehension to filter on creation:

```
b = [x if x not in a else 0 for x in range(200)]
```

The `if x not in a` checks the number isn't suppose to be filtered or not, if it's to be filtered the `else 0` will set it to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do a simple loop? Naive solution is to just do the following:

```
a = [8,5,1, 14]
b = list(range(20))
i = 0 
while (i < len(a)):
  b[a[i]] = 0
  i = i+1
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, this will replace the items in `b` with zero at the indices contained in `a`:

```
for i in a:
    b[i] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension for this.

```
c = [0 for x in b if x in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
for i in b:
    if i in a:
        b[i]=0
```

Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 0):

Simple list comprehension is good for this:

```
a = [2, 4]
b = list(range(10))

[x if x not in a else 0 for x in b]
## [0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```